# check field labels are visible and contain the correct text with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I'm trying to verify that some field labels are visible. I.e. Id, Date, Amount + Description.

How can I check each < dt >  in a < dl >

The are contained in the following < dl > element with css class rec-details.

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal rec-details"> 
<dt> Id </dt> 
<dd class="ng-binding"> 1 </dd> 

<dt> Date </dt> 
<dd class="ng-binding"> 28/01/2015 </dd> 

<dt> Amount (£) </dt> 
<dd class="ng-binding"> -7.24 </dd> 

<dt> Description  </dt> 
<dd class="ng-binding"> 12345 </dd>
```

So basically I just need to check that within the element (with css class rec-details) that ID, Date, Amount + Description are there?

How can this done with protractor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the following should work.

```
var recDetails = element(by.css('.rec-details'));
var data = recDetails.all(by.css('dd'));
var id = data.get(0).getText().then(function(idText) {
  return parseInt(idText);
});
expect(id).toBe(1);

//similar for other data elements
```

But in case if you have access to the source code, i would add css-class to each of your bindings. For example:

```
<dd class=".rec-details-id ng-binding"> 1 </dd>
```

So now you don't have to rely on order of data, and can select element like this:

```
var recDetails = element(by.css('.rec-details'));
var id = recDetails.element(by.css('.rec-details-id'))
                   .getText().then(function(idText) {
                     return parseInt(idText);
                   });
```

Comment: Cool. I think though its just to check that the only labels present are "Id" , "amount" etc. Not too concerned what the values of those fields are.